# Kafka HeartbeatThread BLOCKED

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are using spring kafka version(2.1.5.RELEASE).

After our performance testing while analysing 
thread dump we saw below stack trace which indicates
HeartbeatThread is being blocked by one of the 
Consumer thread

## LOG:

## Consumer Thread Dump

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#4-0-C-1 - priority:5 - threadId:0x00007fca72cf4800 - nativeId:0x5d - nativeId (decimal):93 - state:RUNNABLE
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
- locked <0x000000067e24e1c0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
- locked <0x000000067e24e1a8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
- locked <0x000000067e4415b0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:674)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:396)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:258)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:230)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1164)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1111)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:699)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- <0x000000067e3716b0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync)
```

## HeartbeatThread Dump

```
kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | ccm.device.migration.event 
Stack Trace is: 
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x000000067e3716b0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:224)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:243)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.pollNoWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:297)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatThread.run(AbstractCoordinator.java:948)
- locked <0x000000067e2e0440> (a org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None
```

What could be the probable cause for above observed behaviour?

Comment: Why are you concerned? I don't know the internals, but my understanding is the heartbeat thread is intended to keep the consumer "alive" while the consumer is processing the records received by the `poll()`. So, presumably, it's not needed while the consumer is actually in the `poll()`. See [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread).

Comment: My understanding was also inline with your response.  Since thread dump report mentioned it so thought of checking with expert.  Thanks @GaryRussell